# Lightbox triggers when user hovers off page

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I would like to ask for a help. I copied a simple lightbox popup which is from [tonylea](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-lightbox/).

I wanted to trigger my *lightbox* when user hovers off page. Currently it can be trigger through a click.

```
$('.lightbox').click(function(){
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to make that happen?

Comment: "hovers off page" does that mean when their mouse leaves the browser window?

Comment: Try `mouseout` event.

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeah you're right. when the mouse leaves the browser window.

Comment: @NijrajGelani do you have a sample code to how to use it? I appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can monitor the `mouseleave` event on `document`.

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '.50'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box').animate({
    'opacity': '1.00'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
  console.log('mouse left');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can I make it steady? unless i will click the x button? coz if I always go off page, the lightbox always animate. hmm